# images doesn't fit their relative space

Tags: tailwind-css, swiper.js

I've been trying to make my different size images to fit the whole relative space, but only the second fills it, the first one disappears and the last one fills only half of the space. any thought? i've been using tailwind to style it and swiper.js to flick through the images.

```
      <div className="flex min-h-screen bg-clr1 items-center justify-center py-2 font-avenir">
    <main className="grid grid-cols-2 min-h-screen w-full items-center justify-center px-16 text-center gap-8">
      <div className="text-6xl">
        Exquisite Parfums by Goliath
        <Link href="/novo-produto">
          <h3 className="text-3xl font-bold text-red-200 mt-6">
            Our Collection
          </h3>
        </Link>
      </div>

      <Swiper
        modules={[A11y, Autoplay]}
        spaceBetween={0}
        slidesPerView={1}
        loop={true}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 3000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        className="bg-slate-600 max-w-prose relative"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <Link href="/novo-produto">
            <Image
              src="/img1.jpg"
              alt="parfum1"
              fill
              style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
            ></Image>
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <Link href="/novo-produto">
            <Image
              src="/img2.jpg"
              alt="parfum2"
              width={700}
              height={700}
            ></Image>
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <Link href="/novo-produto">
            <Image
              src="/img3.jpg"
              alt="parfum3"
              width={700}
              height={700}
            ></Image>
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

autoHeight ... can the SwiperJS module script do the adjusting of height for you?